# Appending a child to a SVG object does not update the SVG in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, svg

I have a SVG object and when I click it I want a rectangle to appear there. I can make it work outside of Vue but not with vue.

HTML/template string in Vue

```
<svg id="mysvg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
viewBox="1285 579 475 220" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
<image width="2111" height="1219" xlink:href="./hogviltsgatan.png"></image>
  <g id="local" transform="scale(4)">
    <rect x="50" y="50" width="100" height="100" rx="10" />
  </g>

</svg>
<p id="coords">co-ordinates</p>
```

Vue methods:

```
handleMouseClick(e) {
  var
    t = e.target,
    x = e.clientX,
    y = e.clientY,
    target = (t == this.svg ? this.svg : t.parentNode),
    svgP = this.svgPoint(target, x, y),
    rect = this.createRect(this.NS, svgP.x ,svgP.y, 50, 50);
    target.appendChild(rect);
}


svgPoint(element, x, y){
  let pt = this.svg.createSVGPoint();
  pt.x = x;
  pt.y = y;
  return pt.matrixTransform(element.getScreenCTM().inverse());
},

createRect (svg, x,y, height, width){
  let rect = document.createElementNS(this.svg, 'rect');
    rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', x);
    rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'y', y);
    rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'height', '75');
    rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'width', '50');
    // rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'fill', '#'+Math.round(0xffffff * Math.random()).toString(16));
    return rect;
},

  created() {

    .
    .
    this.svg = document.getElementById('mysvg'),
    this.NS = this.svg.getAttribute('xmlns'),
    this.local = this.svg.getElementById('local'),
    this.coords = document.getElementById('coords');
    .
    .
```

If I print target to console, I can see that the rectangle has been appended. However, it does not appear in my browser. svgPoint & createRect methods work. Again, the code works well outside of Vue. It appears Vue is not updating. If I hardcode a rect in the template string it displays just fine.

Comment: **Typo:** `let rect = document.createElementNS(this.svg, 'rect');` replace `this.svg` with `this.NS`. `this.svg` is an SVGSVGElement, using it as the name-space will make it coerce to the string `"[object SVGSVGElement]"` which is a name-space the browser doesn't know about, and invalid as svg content (apart form inside a foreignObject), but anyway, this won't create an SVGRectElement.

Comment: This also worked very well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create and manipulate an array of objects with the data for your rects

https://jsfiddle.net/53o2fxk6/2/

```
rects : [
   {id: 'id1', x:10, y:10, w:20, h:20},
   {id: 'id2', x:10, y:10, w:20, h:20},
   {id: 'id3', x:10, y:10, w:20, h:20},
   {id: 'id4', x:10, y:10, w:20, h:20}
]
```

manipulate the object

```
createRect: function(_id, _x, _y, _w, _h) {
    this.rects.push({id:_id, x:_x, y:_y, w:_w, h:_h});
}
```

create the SVG with vue methods

```
<svg>
    <g v-for="rect in rects" :id="rect.id" />
        <rect :x="rect.x" :y="rect.x" :width="rect.w" :height="rect.h">
    </g>
</svg>
```